# Code not executed after if condition on JSP page

Tags: java, jsp

I have written the following code on my JSP.

After

```
System.out.println("------------------------medicine-------144444444444-----");
```

line my next sop is not coming.So what is wrong?Please help.

```xml
<%
    System.out.println("------------------------medicine-------144444444444-----");
    if (padetaillist6.get(a).getBph() != null && !padetaillist6.get(a).getBph().isEmpty()) {
%>
<div class = "form-group">
    <label style="width: 50px"  for="BP">BP</label>
    <input type="text" name="txtbph" id="txtbph" placeholder="High Bp"  class="form-control" style="color: black" value="<%=padetaillist6.get(a).getBph()%>">
</div>
/
<div class = "form-group">
    <label style="width: 50px"  for="BP"></label>
    <input type="text" name="txtlbp" id="txtlbp" placeholder="Low Bp"  class="form-control" style="color: black" value="<%=padetaillist6.get(a).getLbp()%>">
</div>
<%
    }
%>
<%
    System.out.println("------------------------medicine-------155555555-----");
    if (!padetaillist6.get(a).getRr().equals("")) {
%>
<div class = "form-group">
    <label style="width: 50px"  for="BP">RR</label>
    <input type="text" name="txtrr" id="txtrr" placeholder="RR" style="color: black"  class="form-control" value="<%=padetaillist6.get(a).getRr()%>">

</div>

<%
    }
%>
```

Comment: Please format your code better.

Comment: what exception you are getting?

Comment: Please post error here.

Comment: i am getting the following last execution.
------------------------medicine-------144444444444-----

Answer (score 0):

Write something n else block for if (padetaillist6.get(a).getBph() != null && !padetaillist6.get(a).getBph().isEmpty()), so that it will give a better idea whether the if condition is satisfying or not. Also check your logs to check NPE. Since are calling padetaillist6.get(a).getBph() directly, there might be a change to get null for padetaillist6.get(a).

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide some more details of the code .?  And I think it is possibly a logical error . The logical errors can be solved only by debugging . Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You must be getting some exception on this JSP page.

As you have not given complete code, I am assuming your exception is getting caught somewhere in code and its not present while giving output of page.

You can add explicit try catch around your if block and add check if it get caught there.